# Prediction errors in orthogonal regression

Tags: regression

I am reading up on orthogonal regression for possible implementation in one of my datasets. My question relates to computation of prediction errors as "mean prediction errors -MPE" or "mean absolute prediction errors-MAPE" in orthogonal regression where my dependent and independent variables (both measured in the same units) may not have the same errors as they may come from different sources.

In normal least squares where the dependent variable is regressed on the independent variable, the MPE or MAPE can be taken from mean of the predicted - observed. How does one compute the MPE or MAPE in the scenario when both the variables have error in them. 
This may be simple but was not obvious to me. Hope the question is clear enough.

VJ

Answer (score 2):

With an error in variables problem like you describe the distance between the data aand the curve should be measured in a different direction.  In the linear model where least squares is applied you assume no error in the Xs and so compute the change in difference in the Ys for fixed value of the Xs. For error in variable models the direction depends on the ratio of variances.  So take the example of simple linear regression (i.e. Y is expressed as a linear function involving only one X covariate).  Then if the error in X and the error in Y have the same variance you measure distance for the observed point to the point of the line in a direction perpendicular to it.  Hence you have the name orthogonal regression.  Once you have the distances calculated for each point MAPE and any othe measure gets calculated in the same way as in the ordinary regression case.

Comment: @MansT I disagree with your rationale for downvoting this answer.  The OP asked how to compute the distance.  While I don't spell out in detail how to calculate the distance, I discribe what the distance is (i.e. the direction from the point to the curve).  That is essentially what you need to know to compute the distances.  MAPE or MSE are then computed in the same way as a function of the distance as they would be in ordinary least squares.  Why would you knit pick my answer like this?  Is it that you like to downvote answers?

Comment: okay I will do that.  I do think it is an answer to the question though. It is just not spelled out in detail.  But I agree that spelling this out improves the anwer.  Thanks for the comment.

Comment: +1 @Michael Thanks. Does that mean that the assumption for orthogonal regression is that the error variance in the X and Y direction have to be the same. What is this assumption does not hold for a problem?

Comment: Yes that is right and in general you can project with a different projection angle.  The projection angle depends on the ratio on the ratio of Var(Y) to Var(X). That is why it is orthogonal when that ratio equals 1.